# Double slit experiment mechanism

Tags: experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, experimental-technique, instrument

1. Can someone explain the mechanism that sets in motion the electrons in the experiment? Is it an electro-magnetic force? If so, I think it's not right to describe the motion of the electron as a 'bullet' that was fired from a gun.
   If there's a mechanism that 'produces' the electro-magnetic field that is located behind the screen, isn't this like  having the electro-magnetic waves travelling the opposite direction of the experiment and passes trough the slits towards the 'gun'?
2. What exactly are the 'detectors'? How do they detect the 'pass' of an electron?
3. Is the experiment 'valid' if we use protons instead of electrons? What is the max mass of the particle in order to get the interference pattern?

Comment: Sigh. Lots of people get hung up on this type of experiment - it is a common entry point into 'weird' physics. You can spend lots of time trying (without success) to find a way around it, or accept it and move on to learn more physics. As for the questions, most simple electron sources use electrostatic fields. Detectors include phosphors and CCDs. Protons will also diffract. It is a strange yet beautiful world out there.

Comment: Another sigh from me. We have hundreds of questions about various double slit experiments (literally, the tag has been used more than 300 times). All of these questions are answered in one or more of them.

Comment: Classical mechanics can be derived from quantum mechanics based on the idea that for large systems the interference between alternate histories will single out that history that satisfies the "least action principle". So, when you observe a macroscopic object satisfying the laws of classical mechanics that then happens because of interference, leaving you with the "stationary phase trajectory".

Comment: Sigh for me also. Thought it wasn't necessary to be a physist in order to put the 'right' question. Another problem is that we - not physists- don't have also any clue about the data of the experiment or the real conditions under which this take place. Yet  a "like" to Jon Custer's comment...

Comment: So single photon sources don't emit single photons?

Comment: as you mentioned this is  'weird' physics to an enginner like me - i google it and found out that probably exists-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the max mass of the particle in order to get the interference pattern?

This article [Physicists Smash Record For Wave-Particle Duality (Nov 8, 2013)](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/physicists-smash-record-for-wave-particle-duality-462c39db8e7b) might answer your question.

I quote from the article:

"*According to quantum mechanics, wave-particle duality and quantum superpositions must also occur for macroscopic objects such as viruses, cells and even baseballs larger objects.
Of course, nobody has seen the quantum superposition of a baseball or anything anywhere near that size. The experiment would be impossibly difficult. But physicists have seen this wave-particle duality for protons, atoms and increasingly large molecules such as buckyballs.
And that raises an interesting question: how big an object can physicists observe behaving like a wave? Today, Sandra Eibenberger at the University of Vienna in Austria and a few pals say they’ve smashed the record for a quantum superposition by **observing wavelike behaviour in giant molecules containing over 800 atoms**.*", [Source](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/physicists-smash-record-for-wave-particle-duality-462c39db8e7b)

Comment: Seriously, [link to the paper or preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8343) in preference to a article about the paper. Science writer are smart hard working people, but the nature of the task in front of them means that essentially *every single article* they write has errors in it. It's built in. The paper contains the real answers.

Comment: dmckee, Again, I do not understand your comment. The article I mentioned is written in such a way that even high school students understand it while the original article uses a more elevated language that can discourage beginners. Add to this that there is no error in the text I quoted. The original says the same thing.